# Error when starting wiican using ChrUbuntu

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, gamepad, wii, chrubuntu

After installing wiican from here: http://www.getdeb.net/install/wiican I can't get the wii remote to connect. When I start the program from the launcher and click on the icon in the top bar, it says "Please load input module first." When I run program from the terminal, it looks like this:

```
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
(wiican:4577): GConf-WARNING **: haven't implemented getting a specific locale in GConfClient
```

And I get the same "Please load input module first" in the top bar icon. When I run the program from the terminal as sudo, I get the same Gconf-WARNING errors and there is no icon present in the top bar.

I am running ChrUbuntu which I believe is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, on an Acer C7 laptop. I have a usb bluetooth wireless receiver, and I've been able to connect a wii remote using wmgui, which was displaying my button inputs. I'm a total linux noob so I may have missed something really basic.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I actually got this to work using xwii instead of wiican. It was 1000x easier.